# Xcode 4.6 hangs at startup

Tags: macos, xcode

Upon opening Xcode, without given the option to do anything else, it opens a blank editor window showing "no selection" with a spinning activity indicator. It then takes up 100% of the CPU for a few minutes until I force quit. How can I stop it from acting like this? I have tried reinstalling and deleting all its cached items and local data.

Comment: Oddly enough deleting a bunch of old stuff from the keychain fixes it. In 8 hours I will add that as the answer.

Reference: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3752773?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a bunch of old certificates and keys from the keychain fixes it in my case.

Reference: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3752773?start=0&tstart=0